# k3s gitlab ci-cd issue with default service account

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, k3s

I am trying to deploy a simple angular app on k3s have installed GitLab-runner have GitLab service  with a Role as a cluster-admin and it is supposed to be able to run all but I can't get it to deploy :

```
rules:
 - apiGroups:
 - ""
  resources:
 - '*'
  verbs:
 - '*'
```

I also tried specifically adding the verb 'apps' - no change in behavior

```
from server for: "deployment.yaml": deployments.apps "gitlab-master" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab-managed-apps:default" cannot get resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "gitlab-managed-apps"
```

Answer (score 1):

So far the only solution is to use the SA with privileges as Gitlab-admin...